# Datamap isn't showing map

Tags: javascript

I used the following repository

https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps

This is the code:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/topojson/1.6.9/topojson.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/datamaps.all.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="position: relative; width: 500px; height: 300px;"></div>

<script>
    var map = new Datamap({
        element: document.getElementById('container'),
        scope: 'pol'
    });
</script>
```

When I change the scope to "usa" the browser shows me a map of the USA.
But when I put "pol" there is nothing...
In the datamaps.all.min.js "pol" is contained...
Other maps don't work either... Only US

Does someone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`datamaps.all.min.js` shows only usa-only map as per this [link](https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps)

For showing world map, you need to use this script during initial import

```
http://datamaps.github.io/scripts/0.4.4/datamaps.world.min.js
```

For poland Map, try this [script URL](https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps/blob/master/dist/datamaps.pol.min.js) instead

Comment: @TomaszJeznach then try  `datamaps.pol.min.js` https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps/tree/master/dist

Comment: @TomaszJeznach Can you share a fiddle of what you tried? If it doesn't work, then I am not sure if this library supports anything else than USA and world.